# How to get the count value from a go-sqlite3 query?

Tags: go, sqlite

I am using [go-sqlite3](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) to retrieve the number of rows with a column of a certain value:

```
query := "select count(notebook) from pages where notebook="
result, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprint(query, id))
```

Where `id` is passed to the function running the query.

How can I retrieve the count value from `result`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
// Output will be stored here.
var output string

id := "1234"

 // Prepare your query
query, err := db.Prepare("select count(notebook) from pages where notebook = ?")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)
}

defer query.Close()

// Execute query using 'id' and place value into 'output'
err = query.QueryRow(id).Scan(&output)

// Catch errors
switch {
case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        fmt.Printf("No notebook with that ID.")
case err != nil:
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
default:
        fmt.Printf("Counted %s notebooks\n", output)
}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on this? I looked as hard as I could on the official repo with no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find much on their repo with respect to documentation. There are a couple of examples though in their repo:

https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/master/_example/simple/simple.go 

The queries themselves are derived from this library:

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query

In your case, you'll likely need to pay particular attention to the 'Row', 'Stmt' and 'Db' sections.